# Login with __RequestVerificationToken cookie before scraping data?

Tags: python, cookies, authentication, python-requests

I want to parse a data from a page but this data is showing only registered users. So, I have to login first then parse it. There is no problem with the parsing side but I have problem on login side. Where am I wrong with?

Here is my only login code:

> I have changed private domain name to domain.com

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = 'https://domain.com/giris?returnUrl=https://domain.com/'
    USERNAME = 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com'
    PASSWORD = '1111111'
    c.get(url)
    __RequestVerificationToken = c.cookies['__RequestVerificationToken']
    login_data = dict(__RequestVerificationToken=__RequestVerificationToken, UserName=USERNAME, Password=PASSWORD, ReturnUrl='https://domain.com/', RememberMe='false')
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://domain.com/giris?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F"})
    page = c.get('https://domain.com/mesaj/')
    print page.content
```

If login is succeeded I need to see `https://domain.com/mesaj/` page but it redirects login page again because of unsuccessful login.

Also, here is the Header of login page that is captures from Google Chrome:

***General***

```
Request URL:https://domain.com/giris
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:176.53.43.2:443
Response Headers
view source
```

***Response Headers***

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:140
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 24 Jan 2017 16:51:30 GMT
Expires:-1
Location:https://domain.com/
Pragma:no-cache
Set-Cookie:a=vjFFqBh+ZZMKr71K2XrBCr5SutOMAOpWjv1RAS5hRYMrR2RojaTV/wgIP8HiUOjdMU7x28DpfxRsCnfSvLeLHPvGTBKjwF0O5W99julK7w23vdctrnE5FDBlhXSSB9nCQm+DB3vNgGjxEr+DNRMrWNwMZWbSQID+klPDtUnReAJQA/GfLdoo2izsD0HP6tir; path=/; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
```

***Request Headers***

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:251
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:iq=c3bae8d44a624f03a431c8df6741af36; __gfp_64b=0icQApqT.NFM3ZR0rZLAyXumlDI4n2eStqQJ74n4H...U7; __gads=ID=bb39b708ca7de25d:T=1484676131:S=ALNI_MYxcRsRoDIaQmsY859bPz_jriFRDA; ASP.NET_SessionId=efsub3xz101y542pyjhugvi2; cookies_info_viewed=yes; notheme=1; __adm_int_sc=1; __adm_int=1; __RequestVerificationToken=xzayOzscFJ3a_m4C5jF8eaKrW7F_Yen7umGMm_nZxDPKmO5rUKacPc4yHK63wVqQwd2S_H2mLiKt_ROW2pCG1B5ZTEtytYF-GU0khK2BlnM1; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.633914475.1484676130; __asc=14f63ba5159d14e81061abc20c9; __auc=328f9ce5159ad97e58cfeb70218
Host:domain.com
Origin:https://domain.com
Referer:https://domain.com/giris?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2F
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
```

***Form Data***

```
__RequestVerificationToken:F2ZCmIge7rSV4A4Xoelf3aweaDQ9vNHew16Bfb6GDSlpeFQeQ_cfmV6UrFhNRWRBqvGPXzXrxVLAIXgbKI-08Q0fD3Vfttezq5hTkMFYTwo1
ReturnUrl:https://domain.com/
UserName:xxxxxxx@gmail.com
Password:1111111
RememberMe:false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests login page before parsing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834397/python-requests-login-page-before-parsing-data)

Comment: Your previous question is totally the same. If you still got no solution, you may "start a bounty" (in case you have enough reputation points). http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty